# Trying to make a mostly silent server

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running an Ubuntu Server, I already have silent enabled in Grub2, so the kernel doesn't show any output.

In addition, I now I want to hide the runlevel/services output. Is that possible?

I don't even mind changing some code in the services system to do this. In other words, the solution doesn't have to be graceful, I just want it to work!

Answer (score 1):

To disable console output during kernel bootup, use the `quiet` option on the kernel command line.

The easiest way to achieve this in case if grub is silent:

Edit `/etc/default/grub` file by adding the kernel parameter:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Then execute following:

```
sudo update-grub
```

**UPDATE:**

In case if you want disable *usplash* graphical splash screen:

Edit `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/conf-hooks.d/usplash` file by adding following:

```
USPLASH=n
```

Then execute following:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```